# Cardboard sample, method must be called from UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, google-cardboard

Trying to develop an app for google cardboard, i downloaded the sample from the official sdk. In the inner class ImageLoaderTask ( which it should be the helper class to manage threading )

```
    class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Uri, Options>, Void, Boolean> {

    /**
     * Reads the bitmap from disk in the background and waits until it's loaded by pano widget.
     */
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Pair<Uri, Options>... fileInformation) {
      Options panoOptions = null;  // It's safe to use null VrPanoramaView.Options.
      InputStream istr = null;
      if (fileInformation == null || fileInformation.length < 1
          || fileInformation[0] == null || fileInformation[0].first == null) {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
          istr = assetManager.open("andes.jpg");
          panoOptions = new Options();
          panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Could not decode default bitmap: " + e);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        try {
          istr = new FileInputStream(new File(fileInformation[0].first.getPath()));
          panoOptions = fileInformation[0].second;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Could not load file: " + e);
          return false;
        }
      }

      panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr), panoOptions);
      try {
        istr.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not close input stream: " + e);
      }

      return true;
    }
  }
```

panoWidgetView is the widget for the panorama, and it is declared inside the activity which includes this inner class.
But Android Studio gives me this error: 
Method loadImageFromBitmap must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker.
Any possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try moving "loadImageFromBitmap" inside onPostExecute :

```
class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Uri, BitmapFactory.Options>, Void, Boolean> {
        Options panoOptions = null;  // It's safe to use null VrPanoramaView.Options.
        InputStream istr = null;

        /**
         * Reads the bitmap from disk in the background and waits until it's loaded by pano widget.
         */
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Pair<Uri, BitmapFactory.Options>... fileInformation) {

            if (fileInformation == null || fileInformation.length < 1
                    || fileInformation[0] == null || fileInformation[0].first == null) {
                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                try {
                    istr = assetManager.open("andes.jpg");
                    panoOptions = new Options();
                    panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not decode default bitmap: " + e);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    istr = new FileInputStream(new File(fileInformation[0].first.getPath()));
                    panoOptions = fileInformation[0].second;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not load file: " + e);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            try {
                istr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close input stream: " + e);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            if( istr!=null && panoOptions!=null){
                 panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr), panoOptions);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect. I cannot perform UI operation in backgroud, thanks!

Comment: Exactly ! https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't call loadImageFromBitmap on the background thread. The method in which you're calling it is doInBackground. If you pass the bitmap to the main thread using the onPostExecute method you can do it there.

Comment: Could you please post also the possible code? Didn't get the last part!

Comment: Ok, I misread your code the first time. Sorry about that. It looks like you are making that call in the onPostExecute method. Are you creating your AsyncTask on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform and UI operation on doInBackground.

You should perform that task on onPostExecute.

But Still you want to implement on doInBackground then you can do with this way

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr), panoOptions); 
        }
    });
```